# Serilog move code configuration to appsettings.json

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-6.0

I'm building a .NET 6 console app. I have it all working with folllowing package references:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Here is my App code for logging:

```
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
      IConfiguration config = builder.Build();

      WorkerOptions opts = config.GetSection("PostConfig").Get<WorkerOptions>();
      string _logFQN = opts.BaseFolder + opts.LogsFolder + opts.LogFname;
      string _LogLevel = opts.LogLevel; // config["PostConfig:LogLevel"];
      var _levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
      switch (_LogLevel[..1].ToUpper())
      {
        case "V":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
          break;
        case "D":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
          break;
        case "I":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
          break;
        case "W":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
          break;
        case "E":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
          break;
        case "F":
          _levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Fatal;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
        .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(_levelSwitch)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
        .WriteTo.Conditional(cond => opts.IsDevelopment, wt => wt.Console(outputTemplate: opts.LogTemplate))
        .WriteTo.File(_logFQN,
                      fileSizeLimitBytes: 524288000,
                      rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                      rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                      outputTemplate: opts.LogTemplate,
                      flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

      Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
```

What I want to do is move code to appsettings.json. I get that'll I'll need to add in code .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder). Can both the appsettings.json combine with the code? If I use readfrom first in the code then use the .Enrich.??? in code will serilog behave. Can I use the conditional through the appsettings.json.

Since this will be used by end users I want to force some things with code and then let the rest be set by appsettings.json.

here is the appsettings.json file:

```json
{
  "PostConfig": {
    "BaseFolder": "./App_Data/",
    "LogsFolder": "logs/",
    "LogFname": "USPS_.Log",
    "LogTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\t{EnvironmentUserName}\t[{Level:u4}]\t<{ThreadId}>\t{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
    "LogLevel": "Verbose",
    "IsDevelopment": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this.  I want a smart file name, which includes the Process ID.  Easy in code, but I do not see how in the json file settings.